# Scale TextField with 16dp on both sides

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, textfield

I'm trying to put an InputTextField in the middle of the screen with a margin of 16dp on the right and the left side. What should I write into android:layout_width? android:layout_width="??"

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="???dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:hint="YourText"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: please look at my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **put your edittext in a** `relativelayout` **and add padding to your relativelayout**. Then you would set the `android_width` of your `relativelayout` to `match_parent`. To do so do this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="matchParent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:hint="YourText"
    android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what the parent `ViewGroup` is. If your parent `ViewGroup` is a `RelativeLayout`, you should use:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
```

For any other layout type, you should use:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

instead of:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: This is the same a superser suggested. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @REEKApps Slightly different; you shouldn't need to wrap it in another layout, but yes, same concept. :)